# Callback of chrome.tabs.create is not triggered in a popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing my first chrome extension, which should open an URL in a new tab and after that do something.

**manifest:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

**script.js:**

```
function toggle() {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: "http://google.com" }, function(tab) {
        alert("Hello!");
        });
 }

document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', toggle);
```

**popup.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="toggle" class="clickable">START</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that nothing happens after the URL is opened. What can be the problem?

Comment: Did the popup close after the tab was created?

Comment: @RobW yes, it is closing

Comment: Then why are you surprised that the script stopped running? If you want the script to continue running, run it from the background page.

Comment: @RobW This is the correct answer! I did not know I should call background function, thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create a new tab, by default it opens focused, and that causes the popup to close. When the popup closes, its JavaScript context is destroyed and there's no callback left to call.

You have 2 options:

1. Move logic to the [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)/[event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), which will survive the popup being closed. For example, instead of opening the tab from the popup, you can [message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) the background page to do it for you.
2. [Specify](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) that you want to open the tab unfocused:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.create(
     {
       url: "http://google.com",
       active: false 
     }, function(tab) {
       /* ... */
     }
   );
   ```

   However, this won't simply cause the tab to not focus - Chrome won't switch to it (opening it in the background). Might not be what you want. You can switch after your other operations are done though - with `chrome.tabs.update` to set `active: true`.

Note that there is no way for a popup to survive focus loss, this is by design.

Comment: Credit where it's due, RobW's comment diagnosed the situation. This is just more detail on the matter.

Comment: Thanks, Google. So glad they arbitrarily decided to make opening a LINK this difficult.